# Are there any GOOD javascript addins for Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide

In our daily work we maintain some rather large Javascript libaries. We use VS2008 and while they made some improvements to the Javascript IDE, I still find it lacking. There is no outlining, no collapsing, or other ways to keep the code organized.

I have tried [js-addin](http://code.google.com/p/js-addin/) and [JSLint](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/JSLintVS.aspx) which crash and don't have the features I want, respectively.  I have actually gone as far as running [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.org/) as their Javascript IDE is much better than what I can get out of Visual Studio. I'm getting tired of having to maintain 2 IDE's. Is there anything out there that can make Javascript editing less painful in Visual Studio 2008? (We don't have the option of 2010 yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I have found nothing to my liking. I am finding I use aptana studio now for my client side work. It just does what I need. Hopefully someday the VS team will actually make a full featured IDE for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding VS 2010: I am using it for a few months, and I did not see any significant improvement to JavaScript support.